# PowerShell Invoke-Command using Start-Process is not creating log file

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I have a command line exe on a remote server which I need to execute remotely (running on the remote server).  This exe connects to the DB, and writes a log file.

I have enabled WinRM by executing these PowerShell commands:

1. `netsh http add iplisten localip {add local ip here}`
2. `netsh http add iplisten 127.0.0.1`
3. `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force`
4. `Enable-PSRemoting -Force`

This works and I was able to test by executing

```
Test-WSMan {computername}
```

I am now trying to execute the command line exe via `Invoke-Command` and expecting a log file entry to be created with this script.

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName MyServer –ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process "C:\TheRemotePath\ToTheExe.exe"
}
```

PowerShell does not display any errors. However, no log file is generated.  I have full rights to the directory of the exe as well as the log file directory.  I am able to successfully run the exe via Windows Explorer (navigate to the remote exe and double click to run).

Any idea why this does not seem to work or what tools I can use to try and diagnose?

Comment: What log would you expect to be created, and where? Are you sure that the logfile isn't just created in a different place? Did you try `Set-Location "C:\some\folder"` before running the executable? Did you try the call operator instead of `Start-Process`?

Comment: The exe has a configuration (uses log4Net to log) to log.  It currently logs in the same directory as where the exe is.  I haven't tried that.  I will try that shortly.  I assumed that the exe is running in the directory (on the server) where it is hosted.  Is this not the case?  (I am able to echo a file to the directory, so I know that this is not a permissions issue.  PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName myServer -ScriptBlock { echo test > C:\Playground\log\test.tx })

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` and `$PWD.Path` aren't necessarily the same, no.

Comment: Thank you!!  This was the issue.  I was able to fix as such.  Set-Location \\MyServer\c$\MyDirectory
Invoke-Command –ComputerName MyServer –ScriptBlock { & "c:\MyDirectory\MyApp.Console.exe" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try testing the path and switching to the call operator as Ansgar mentioned, i.e.:

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName MyServer –ScriptBlock {
    $path = "C:\TheRemotePath\ToTheExe.exe"
    if (Test-Path $path) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Confirmed access to $path!"
        & $path
    }
    else {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Unable to reach $path!"
    }
}
```

Doing those will help you diagnose where it's getting tripped up. Depending on the EXE, I've had to use different methods of starting the process from Powershell.

Comment: Yes.  I added a comment to Ansgar.  His comment was the solution, but marking yours as such, as his is just a comment which I can't mark as answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the working directory to the location of your executable before running it. I would also recommend using the call operator (`&`) instead of `Start-Process`, unless you have reason to use the latter.

```
Invoke-Command –ComputerName MyServer –ScriptBlock {
  Set-Location 'C:\MyDirectory'
  & 'MyApp.Console.exe'
}
```