# How do I open a exe on a remote computer

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I need a powershell script that I can run from a host computer that will restart a exe (like excel or something) on a remote computer.

I've tried using possession, invoke-command, and psexec, but to no avail.
I even thought of a way to be on a host computer, and try to execute a script that is on the remote server. 
I don't get any errors for these, which makes it hard to know what's happening/if it's even happening.

I've tried this in my scripts: 
& EXCEL.exe

I expect the application to open on the remote computer.

Comment: Have you tried WinRM? I've used this successfully in the past to run non graphical (commands line) scripts / exes. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43744850/1265167

Comment: What are you trying to do in Excel? Excel is designed to work with a graphical user interface, thus starting it in "unattended mode" may have undesired consequences. However, I have had issues starting applications remotely, that I ended up creating a scheduled task on the target computer that would launch the application, then I would trigger the scheduled task remotely. Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/start-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps

Comment: Claire, I have tried WinRM, but the graphical exe wouldn't open.

Comment: JPortillo, thanks for the link! I was able to get it working by creating a task to run the exe. I'm just working out the kinks now of how/when I want it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my question. I made a generic version of what I ended up doing:

```
$remoteComputer = "ComputerName"

$appLocation = "C:\Windows\notepad"

$taskName = "openNotepad"

$delay = (get-date).AddMinutes(1) #adds 1 minute to the current time

$newTime = get-date $delay -format HH:mm:ss #24 HR format

echo (get-date -Uformat %T)

echo $newTime #compare the time difference

$null = schtasks /create /s $remoteComputer /TN $taskName /TR $appLocation /SC ONCE /ST $newTime

start-sleep -s 65 #schtasks can't perform on the same minute, and needs a wait time before it will delete the task

$null = schtasks /delete /s $remoteComputer /TN $taskName /f
```